# RegEx for matching strings not started with a number passing alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am looking for a regex that only accepts numbers and letters and the first character cannot start with a number.

I found an OK solution that doesn't work all the time by doing:

```
export const cannotBeginWithAdigit= new RegExp("/^d/");
export const canOnlyContainNumsbersAndDigits = new RegExp('/[,"/\\[]:|<>+=.;?*]/g');
```

I place the regex between an || to test the first one then the second one.

Other that doesn't work:

```
^d{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Use; `/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can start (`^`) our expression with a not-start-with digits (`[^\d]`) followed by a list of our desired chars:

```
^[^\d][A-Za-z0-9]+
```

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9tuPTV/1)

Then, we can also add additional boundaries. For example, [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s advice in the comment is good by adding an end char and using `i` flag:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^[^\d][A-Za-z0-9]+/gm;
const str = `123abc
abc123abc
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try `/^\D{1}\w+$/`

Explanation:

`\D` means select only non numeric, `{1}` limits the match to single letter. `\w` is word match, it matches all alphanumeric, but no other characters. `+` to make sure there is more than one letter in `\w` match. You can modify it to fit your requirements.

Comment: You don't need the `{1}`, that's already inferred, and it should be `\w*` instead of `\w+` because a single character matches the conditions specified by OP but is not matched by your regex.

Comment: also, `\w` will match underscore `_`